# Getting the id of clicked element

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code that allows me to change the colour and text of the href when clicked.

```js
/* Changing the colour of the button upon clicked */
function changecolor(element) {
  alert(element.target.id);
  if (element.innerHTML == "Select") {
    element.innerHTML = "Selected";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0"; /*Grey*/
    element.style.borderColor = "#C0C0C0";
    alert(element);
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = "Select";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#FED136"; /*Yellow*/
    element.style.borderColor = "#FED136";
    alert(element);
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" id="<?php echo $rowModelList['modelName']?>" onClick="return changecolor(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
```

1. The default text and colour of the href is "Select" and is in yellow colour.
2. Once clicked on it, the colour will change to gray and the text will
   be "Selected".

However, I am also trying to get the id of the clicked href and store in a variable. I tried "`alert(element.target.id);`" but I got "undefined".

Any idea how I can modify the code to get the id?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `alert(element.id)`. `target` is a property of an event, not an element.

```js
/* Changing the colour of the button upon clicked */
function changecolor(element) {
  alert(element.id);
  if (element.innerHTML == "Select") {
    element.innerHTML = "Selected";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0"; /*Grey*/
    element.style.borderColor = "#C0C0C0";
    alert(element);
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = "Select";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#FED136"; /*Yellow*/
    element.style.borderColor = "#FED136";
    alert(element);
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" id="<?php echo $rowModelList['modelName']?>" onClick="return changecolor(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
```